# PLS-0013: Encoutered the symbol "C_NOTES" when expecting one of the following : :=,(@%:

Tags: oracle, plsql

Does anybody know how to resolve my problem because i think the syntax is good but the compiler show me this message error. I don't know what it is because everything is correct from my pov..
these are my procedure and my package spec/body

### Stand-alone procedure compiles fine

```
CREATE or REPLACE procedure pr_resultat
IS
   CURSOR  c_notes    is
    select avg(points) moy, num_eleve
    from resultats
    group by num_eleve;

    result varchar(20) := '';
BEGIN
   for elem in c_notes LOOP
       if elem.moy < 10 then
        result := 'failure';
       elsif elem.moy >= 10 and elem.moy < 12 then
        result := 'average';
       elsif elem.moy >= 12 and elem.moy < 14 then
        result := 'pretty good';
       elsif elem.moy >= 14 and elem.moy < 16 then
        result := 'good';
       elsif elem.moy >= 16 then
        result := 'very good';
       end if;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(elem.num_eleve || '->' || result);
   end loop;
END;
/
```

### Package header compiles fine

```
create or replace package package_prcd
is
    procedure pr_resultat;
end package_prcd;
/
```

### Package body results in a compile error

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "C_NOTES" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; in line 6

```
create or replace package body package_prcd
is
    procedure pr_resultat
    IS
    begin
        CURSOR  c_notes is  
        select avg(points) moy, num_eleve
        from resultats
        group by num_eleve;

        result varchar(20) := '';

        for elem in c_notes LOOP
           if elem.moy < 10 then
            result := 'failure';
           elsif elem.moy >= 10 and elem.moy < 12 then
            result := 'average';
           elsif elem.moy >= 12 and elem.moy < 14 then
            result := 'pretty good';
           elsif elem.moy >= 14 and elem.moy < 16 then
            result := 'good';
           elsif elem.moy >= 16 then
            result := 'very good';
           end if;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(elem.num_eleve || '->' || result);
        end loop;
    end;
end package_prcd;
/
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/lxZvALDe

Comment: There are three parts you are showing: a stand-alone procedure, a package header, and a package body. It would have been helpful to tell us in which of the three the error occurs and in what line. I've edited your request with this information.

Answer (score 0):

In your package body you mistakenly moved the procedure's `BEGIN` before the declarations (cursor and result variable). It must come after the declarations (before the loop).